# Proving that the Henyey-Greenstein phase function is normalized?

Tags: integration

What I am aiming to do is prove that the Henyey-Greenstein phase function, that's used to model the angular distribution of out-scattered light in participating medium is indeed normalized. The function is like this:

$p(\theta) = {1 \over {4\pi}}{{1 - g^2} \over {(1 + g^2 - 2g\cos\theta)^{3/2}}}$

Where $\cos\theta$ is the the dot product between the view direction and the incident light direction and $-1 \leq g \leq 1$ is a variables that controls whether scattering is essentially backward, forward (or isotropic when g=0). So $\theta$ varies from 0 to $\pi$ and $\cos\theta$ from 1 to -1. So using this the function is often written as:

$p(g, \mu) = {1 \over {2}}{{1 - g^2} \over {(1 + g^2 - 2g\mu)^{3/2}}}$

Where $\mu=\cos(\theta)$

So I often see (for the integral part with the result showing it's normalized):

$\int_{-1}^{1} p(g, \mu)d\mu = 1, \text{ for any g}$

What I would like to achieve is prove the point above. I do know how to find the anti-derivative of the H-G function and I know about the second fundamental theorem of calculus but I am little confused on how to apply them here because the function has two variables it seems to me: $g$ which can vary from -1 to 1 (the anisotropy factor I believe it's called) and $\mu$. How to prove that this integral over the phase function as written above being equal to 1 is true for all values of g?

Should I first integrate the function which would give me:

${{(1-g^2)} \over {2g}} {({{1}\over{(1-g)}} - {{1}\over{(1+g)}})}$

And then integrate this over g from -1 to 1? Is that how I am supposed to do it?

If someone could put me on the right track I would very much appreciate.

PS: I have a bonus question. It seems to me that when g=1 or -1 for that matter, $p(\mu)$ = 0. Which doesn't seem to me like a result you would like to use as an angular distribution. So it seems like values for g = 1 or -1 are not working even though I see in the literature that they seem to be accepted? If you have an insight on this as well, I'd be very happy if you could share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} p(g, \mu)d\mu =\frac12 \int_{-1}^{1} 
{{1 - g^2} \over {(1 + g^2 - 2g\mu)^{3/2}}}d\mu
=\frac{1 - g^2}{2g (1 + g^2 - 2g\mu)^{1/2}}\bigg|_{-1}^1=1
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much @Quanto. My problem is that when I expand the equation I get ${{(1-g^2)} \over {2g}} {({{1}\over{(1-g)}} - {{1}\over{(1+g)}})}$. And I don't understand how this can be equal to 1? Sorry my post could have been shorter if I had explained that. Many thanks for your patience. I am not super smart but really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MarcOurens - Note 
$${{(1-g^2)} \over {2g}} {\left({{1}\over{1-g}} - {{1}\over{1+g}}\right)}
={{(1-g^2)} \over {2g}} {{{(1+g)-(1-g)}\over{(1-g)(1+g)}}}=1
$$